# Difference between '{' and '['  when formatting JSON object

Tags: json

Is there any difference between '{' and '[' when formatting a JSON object?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Yep one `{...}` is used to define a single object, while the other `[...]` is used to define a sequence of either objects, values or lists  ...

objects are defined as such `{key:object or list or value , ...}`
list ares nothing more than a sequence of either objects or lists or values, `[objects or list or values, ... ]`...

`[{'value':1}, {'values':[1,2,3,3, {'a':'a', 'b':'b'}]}, 2, 3, 4]`

Comment: Fantastic answer. Straight to the point and easy to understand.

Answer (score 35):

'`{ }` ' used for **Object** and '`[]`' is used for **Array** in json

Like

```
var sampleObj = {
                a:1,
                b:'ab'
                };


var sampleArr = [1,'ab',4];
```

Answer (score 8):

They don't have the same meaning at all. `{}` denote containers, `[]` denote arrays.

Comment: Yep! You are right! I liked your answer because it define it in different way. thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
package ravi.kumar;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.lang.Object;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
public class SetListClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SetListClass SetListClass = new SetListClass();
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("country");
        list.add("state");
        list.add("distract");
        list.add("country");
        System.out.println(list);
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------");
        SetListClass.getset();
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------");
        SetListClass.getHashMap();
    }
    public void getset()
    {
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
        set.add("country");
        set.add("state");
        set.add("distract");
        set.add("country");
        System.out.println(set);
        System.out.println(set.remove("country"));
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(set);
    }
    public void getHashMap() {
        HashMap<String, Object> hashmap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hashmap.put("country", "india");
        hashmap.put("state", "bihar");
        hashmap.put("district", "buxar");
        System.out.println(hashmap);
    }
}



output
-------
[country, state, distract, country] ------array
----------------------------------------------
[state, distract, country] ----array
true
---------------------------------------------
[state, distract]
----------------------------------------------
{state=bihar, district=buxar, country=india}  ---Object
```

Comment: map contains key value pair, keys are nothing but set and values are nothing but list.