# Microsoft graph patch content to excel online ,but all rows are empty

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

i am trying to patch content to a excel file, but nothing appears, not sure why.
`patch https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/drivesID/items/ItemId/workbook/worksheets/Sheet1/range(address='A1:W1083')`
，

the json object is https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/g51xBUHp

Comment: looks like i cant post all json data online

Comment: Please format your json.

Comment: just use pastebin to insert all json data. total 1083, but cant make it work.

Comment: The data cannot be used. You can try to upload small data which can reproduce your issue.

Comment: hi, what do you mean the data can not be used, you mean it is too big ?

Comment: I even tried 3 rows of data, the patch response is ok, but no data shown in excel.  no error report, but no idea why the data is not shown

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the problem, so the data posted to excel online can not be {} json data, meaning, no key referenced, so the data must use array_values() to extract, and then patch.
Referecning [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11045639/difference-between-and-when-formatting-json-object)!