# String Can't Json in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a like this object as a string. if that object like this below, no problem

```
var txt = '{ "title": "001188", "name": "Input 1", "data": "false" }'
var arr = [];
var obj = JSON.parse(txt);
arr.push(obj)
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = arr[0].name;
```

but if I try to convert this object, there was an error

```
var txt = '{ "title": "001188", "name": "Input 1", "data": "false" }, { "title": "001188", "name": "Input 2", "data": "false" }, { "title": "001188", "name": "Input 3", "data": "false" }, { "title": "001188", "name": "Input 4", "data": "false" }, { "title": "001188", "name": "Input 5", "data": "false" }'
var arr = [];

var obj = JSON.parse(txt);
arr.push(obj)
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = arr[0].name;
```

Error is below

> Unexpected token , in JSON at position 57

How can I do this. Thanks

Comment: Your second example is _not_ JSON. It is multiple JSON-encoded objects, listed just comma-separated one after each other. Easiest way to solve this, would probably be to add `[` and `]` at the beginning and end, so that you have an _array_ of objects, which would be proper JSON again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your JSON is invalid. The objects in your JSON have to be in an array. Something like this:

```
[{ "title": "001188", "name": "Input 1", "data": "false" }, { "title": "001188", "name": "Input 2", "data": "false" }, { "title": "001188", "name": "Input 3", "data": "false" }, { "title": "001188", "name": "Input 4", "data": "false" }, { "title": "001188", "name": "Input 5", "data": "false" }]
```

instead of

```
{ "title": "001188", "name": "Input 1", "data": "false" }, { "title": "001188", "name": "Input 2", "data": "false" }, { "title": "001188", "name": "Input 3", "data": "false" }, { "title": "001188", "name": "Input 4", "data": "false" }, { "title": "001188", "name": "Input 5", "data": "false" }
```

And then parse your JSON. Also, you don't have to push the parsed result into an array as it will create a 2D array unnecessarily.

```js
var txt = '[{ "title": "001188", "name": "Input 1", "data": "false" }, { "title": "001188", "name": "Input 2", "data": "false" }, { "title": "001188", "name": "Input 3", "data": "false" }, { "title": "001188", "name": "Input 4", "data": "false" }, { "title": "001188", "name": "Input 5", "data": "false" }]'

var arr = JSON.parse(txt);
console.log(arr[0].name);
```

Comment: thanks. my problem has been solved by your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
var txt = '[{ "title": "001188", "name": "Input 1", "data": "false" }, { "title": "001188", "name": "Input 2", "data": "false" }, { "title": "001188", "name": "Input 3", "data": "false" }, { "title": "001188", "name": "Input 4", "data": "false" }, { "title": "001188", "name": "Input 5", "data": "false" }]'
var arr = [];

var obj = JSON.parse(txt);
arr.push(obj)
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = arr[0].name;
```

Can you try this?
The [ ] were missing it seems.

Answer (score 0):

`{...}` is used to define a single object, while the other `[...]` is used to define a sequence of either objects, values or lists `...`

objects are defined as such `{key:object or list or value , ...}` list are nothing more than a sequence of either objects or lists or values, `[objects or list or values, ... ]`...

```
[{'value':1}, {'values':[1,2,3,3, {'a':'a', 'b':'b'}]}, 2, 3, 4]
```

Just enclose you array of json objects in `[...]`

```
var txt = '[{ "title": "001188", "name": "Input 1", "data": "false" }, { "title": "001188", "name": "Input 2", "data": "false" }, { "title": "001188", "name": "Input 3", "data": "false" }, { "title": "001188", "name": "Input 4", "data": "false" }, { "title": "001188", "name": "Input 5", "data": "false" }]'
var arr = [];

var obj = JSON.parse(txt);

arr.push(obj)

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = arr[0].name;
```

reference from an [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11045639/difference-between-and-when-formatting-json-object/11045748) on  stackoverflow